# Google maps api v3 draw polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I'm new in javascript so i have problem with drawing polyline on my map. I'm receiving coordinates from GPS in vehicle and i want to draw car movement. So for i put markers on the places my car passed, but i'm not sure how to add polyline. Can anybody help me?

I've written this so far:

```
    var map;
    var markers=[];
    var timeout=5000;
    var interval=null;

    function init2(){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.7997016667,15.97143);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        update_markers();
    }
    function update_markers(){
        console.log('update...');
        for(var x in markers){
            markers[x].setMap(null);
        }
        markers=[];
        $.getJSON('/get',
            function(d){
                var l=d.length;
                for(var x=l-5;x<l;x++){
                    var f1=parseFloat(d[x].lat);
                    var f2=parseFloat(d[x].long);
                    if(f1>100){
                        continue;
                        f1=f1/100.0;
                        f2=f2/100.0;
                    }

                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(f1, f2),
                        map: map,
                        title: d[x].time
                    }));
                }
            }
        );
        interval=setTimeout(update_markers, timeout);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init2);

    $(function(){
        $('#timeout_sel').change(function(){
            clearTimeout(interval);
            timeout=$(this).val();
            update_markers();
        });
    });
```

And i don't know how to put this into my code:

```
    function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
      new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can you give me some tips? The second code is from google examples and it uses fixed latlng, how do i add this in may update_markers function so it uses the same coordinates as marker?

EDIT:

```
    var map;
    var markers=[];
    var timeout=5000;
    var interval=null;
    var flightPlanCoordinates=[];

    function init2(){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.7997016667,15.97143);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        update_markers();
    }
    function update_markers(){
        console.log('update...');
        for(var x in markers){
            markers[x].setMap(null);
        }
        markers=[];
        $.getJSON('/get',
            function(d){
                var l=d.length;
                for(var x=l-5;x<l;x++){
                    var f1=parseFloat(d[x].lat);
                    var f2=parseFloat(d[x].long);
                    if(f1>100){
                        continue;
                        f1=f1/100.0;
                        f2=f2/100.0;
                    }

                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(f1, f2),
                        map: map,
                        title: d[x].time
                    }));
                    flightPlanCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(f1,f2);
                 }
                 var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: flightPlanCoordinates,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
             });
            }
        );
        interval=setTimeout(update_markers, timeout);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init2);

    $(function(){
        $('#timeout_sel').change(function(){
            clearTimeout(interval);
            timeout=$(this).val();
            update_markers();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at your current code and the code you want to add. Do you see that some parts are common between the two, or at least very similar, and some parts are different? You already have the common parts, now you need to add the different parts. Specifically, that will be the three statements that create the `flightPlanCoordinates` and the `flightPath` and adds that to the map.

Comment: With regard to the specific question of how to use the marker latlngs instead of the hard coded values, do this: (1) Create an empty array before your marker loop with `var flightPlanCoordinates = [];` (2) Each time you add a marker, push the same `LatLng` value (your `position`) onto that array. (3) After the loop, create the new `PolyLine` and add it to the map.

Comment: i edited post so you can correct me if i'm doing something wrong. i did first and second thing. but i'm not sure how to: add it to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a update based on your updated code. This should be pretty close. You need to *push* each position onto the `flightPlanCoordinates` array, not assign to that variable. Also that array doesn't need to be global. Regarding adding the polyline to the map, that's either the `.setMap()` call in the original code, or you can use the `map` property when you create the polyline, as you do for the markers and shown in the code below.

I also pushed the polyline onto the `markers` array so it will be removed along with the markers. You may want to change the name of this array to reflect that it's not just markers but basically is everything you want to clear from the map on an update.

I also moved this clearing code into the `$.getJSON()` callback instead of doing it before you make the call. This will give a smoother update instead of blanking the markers and polyline for a short time while you wait for the new data.

Another tip: never use a `for`..`in` loop on an array (the loop that clears the markers from the map with `setMap(null)`). Use a numeric `for` loop instead.

```
var map;
var markers=[];
var timeout=5000;
var interval=null;

function init2(){
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.7997016667,15.97143);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatlng,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    update_markers();
}
function update_markers(){
    console.log('update...');
    $.getJSON('/get',
        function(d){
            for(var i = 0;  i < markers.length;  ++i){
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers=[];
            var polylineCoordinates = [];
            var l=d.length;
            for(var x=l-5;x<l;x++){
                var f1=parseFloat(d[x].lat);
                var f2=parseFloat(d[x].long);
                if(f1>100){
                    continue;
                    f1=f1/100.0;
                    f2=f2/100.0;
                }

                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(f1, f2);
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: d[x].time
                }));
                polylineCoordinates.push( position );
            }
            markers.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                map: map,
                path: polylineCoordinates,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            }));
        }
    );
    interval=setTimeout(update_markers, timeout);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init2);

$(function(){
    $('#timeout_sel').change(function(){
        clearTimeout(interval);
        timeout=$(this).val();
        update_markers();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're brilliant!! It's working! Thanks for tips, they are really helpful.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, I am getting an error, 
<p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&amp;1i67108740&amp;2i67108718&amp;2e2&amp;3u19&amp;4m2&amp;1u249&amp;2u292&amp;5m5&amp;1e2&amp;5sen-US&amp;6sus&amp;10b1&amp;12b1&amp;token=2152</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins></p>

Can you please guide what is this error about and any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: @AkashJain That doesn't seem to be related to this issue, so could you post it as a new question? Be sure to include a working (i.e. broken) test case that reproduces the issue, preferably as a code snippet in the question, or else as a JSFiddle or CodePen or the like. That will make it much easier for someone to look at. The 404 error alone isn't a lot to go on. Feel free to @ me after you post the question if you want. Thanks!